# How to create a picklist field using jQuery and replace a text field with that picklist?

Tags: jquery, salesforce

I have standard page in Salesforce. I cannot modify this page. But what I can do is add javascript or jQuery to this page. I have to replace a inputtext field with a picklist value. I want to build this pikclist using jQuery, the picklist values will be dynamically populated, and replace a input text with this picklist.

I am not sure how to use the `.replaceWith()` function. please help me out!!

Comment: A pick-list should have multiple selection options so I don't understand how you will transform a text input into a pick-list.. `.replaceWith` should be used like `$('#my_id').replaceWith('<div id="my-pick-list"></div>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.replaceWith()` with you input box like this

```
$('#YourInputId').replaceWith('<select multiple="multiple" id="YourPicklistId"></select>');
```

and after that you can append options to your picklist using `append`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I added the below code and it worked fine. But the requirement is to store the value of the selected picklist value in the input text field, which I am unable to do so. Any idea how to go about it?<script>var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();j$(document).ready(function(){j$("[name*=country]").val( function(){return j$(j$(this).replaceWith('<select id="justId"><option>India</option><option>US</option></select>')).text();}).hide();});</script>